Build OpenCV's Core & ImgProc using Emscripten & CMake
When trying to build OpenCV's core and imgproc modules ONLY using a custom emcmake command, the build will fail due to deprecated wasm related keywords upon using emmake ninja install
System: Windows 11
Shell: MINGW64 (bash)
Command:
emcmake cmake -G Ninja -S statics/opencv -B statics/opencv/static_build -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=emsdk/upstream/emscripten/em++ -D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/ninja-win/ninja.exe -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=statics/opencv/static_build/install -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gapi=OFF -D WITH_IPP=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF -D WITH_1394=OFF -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF -D WITH_GSTREAMER=OFF -D WITH_GTK=OFF -D WITH_JPEG=OFF -D WITH_PNG=OFF -D WITH_TIFF=OFF -D WITH_WEBP=OFF -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_VTK=OFF -D WITH_LAPACK=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_ml=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_photo=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_video=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_calib3d=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_features2d=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_flann=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF -D WITH_ITT=OFF -D WITH_JPEG2000=OFF -D ENABLE_PIC=OFF -D WITH_ZLIB=ON

ERROR:
opencv/modules/core/include\opencv2/core/hal/intrin_wasm.hpp:2088:18: warning: 'wasm_v8x16_shuffle' is deprecated: use 'wasm_i8x16_shuffle' instead [-W#pragma-messages]
2088 |     v128_t t10 = wasm_v8x16_shuffle(t00, t01, 0,1,2,3,12,13,14,15,24,25,26,27,4,5,6,7);
     |                  ^
opencv/modules/core/include\opencv2/core/haintrin_wasm.hpp:2728:22: warning: 'wasm_v8x16_shuffle' is deprecated: use asm_i8x16_shuffle' instead [-W#pragma-messages]
2728 |     return v_int16x8(wasm_v8x16_shuffle(vec.val, vec.val, 0,1,2,3,5,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,6,7));
     |                      ^
emsdk\upstream\lib\clang\20\include\wasm_simd128.h:1746:3: te: expanded from macro 'wasm_v8x16_shuffle'
1746 |   __DEPRECATED_WASM_MACRO("wasm_v8x16_shuffle", "wasm_i8x16_shuffl)
     |   ^          
emsdk\upstream\lib\clang\20\include\wasm_simd128.h:1687:3: te: expanded from macro '__DEPRECATED_WASM_MACRO'
1687 |   _Pragma(__WASM_STR(GCC warning(                                            
     |   ^
:3:6: note: expanded from here
3 |  GCC warning( "'" "wasm_v8x16_shuffle" "' is deprecated: use '" "wm_i8x16_shuffle" "' instead")
  |
more warnings (186) errors (9).

I suppose one could keyword replace, but I decided to keep looking for the moment...
So, I then explored opencv/platforms/js/build_js.py, which is a python script that is meant to build OpenCV.js, but that failed for me as well, in a number of different ways.
I tried the recommended commands from the documentation and the command failed because the generator flag being auto appended to my command '-G Ninja' (a recommended tool, seen in many different CMakeList's across the library as acceptable) however even when tweaking the script to accept it, the command still fails. This is likely a Windows problem. (ATTOW: trying WSL)
If anyone can reproduce the above and/or provide steps to build the core and imgproc modules only successfully on any system that would be greatly appreciated - excluding the available precompiled 4.x opencv.js from https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/opencv.js
Thanks All

The error is not shown in your question.

@bleater The error is in fact those warnings being thrown during build, and then the make process fails due to deprecated support not being opted out of with cmake flags such as -DCV_ENABLE_INTRINSICS=OFF, -DBUILD_WASM_INTRIN_TESTS=OFF. Passing such flags ensure the make process exits cleanly. I will be re-attempting a build soon
